# Creating topic in publisher (ZeroMQ)

Tags: c, zeromq

I've been writing code for a PUB-SUB ZeroMQ system (in C), with one publisher and multiple subscribers.
On the client code, I must subscribe to a topic, according to a filter, like so:

```
(...)
void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
void *subscriber = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_SUB);
int rc = zmq_connect (subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5555");

char *filter = (argc > 1)? argv [1]: "10001 "; // example of a filter
rc = zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen (filter));
(...)
```

However, looking at code examples of the publisher (seen in the documentation of ZeroMQ), I don't see any line where the topic is created:

```
(...)
void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
void *publisher = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_PUB);
int rc = zmq_bind (publisher, "tcp://*:5556");

while (1) {
    (...)
    char update [20];
    sprintf (update, "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
    s_send (publisher, update);
    (...)
```

The message is simply sent and no topic is specified. How is this possible?

In python versions, I've seen, in the publisher code:

```
socket.send_string("%d %d" % (topic, number))
```

but I have not seen anything like this in C.

Comment: Nothing forces you to emit a topic. Sorry, ZeroMQ is very tolerant in that aspect, though things may not work as intended then. Can you please provide a [mcve] of code that you need explained? There's too much code left out and people shouldn't have to guess in order to know what you did.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt not really... he is clearly asking "how do you subscribe to a topic in zmq" and lays out all the code that one would need to do so. In fact, his code works, he just doesn't understand why, which is simple to answer.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero.

All bytes of the message are considered as The ***Topic*** and the subscriber-side specified "Topic-filtering" operates on trivial and plain byte-matching of the set of subscribed-to topics against the left-n-bytes of the message.

Those messages, that match any of the recorded Topic(s) are considered as messages to be delivered, those not matching any one are not ( except when an inverse matching option was set )

Answer (score 4):

Publishers don't explicity set topics in ZMQ. Topics are implied by the message, starting from the first character. The python code example is just a simple string concatenation that adds the "topic" to the front of the message.

Say you publish a message:

`Hello - I am a ZMQ message`

subscribing to

`H`

`Hello`

`Hello -`

Will all receive your message.